# Jenkins - how do I reload remote Tomcat in Windows from Jenkins in Linux server?

Tags: linux, tomcat, jenkins

I successfully built a `.war` file and deployed to remote Tomcat in Windows server from Jenkins in CentOS 7. Now I want to make Jenkins let the remote Windows server reload Tomcat after the `.war` file is successfully deployed. So I went to `Execute Windows batch command` and wrote the following script.

```
set JAVA_HOME=D:\Java\jdk1.6

cd "D:\Java\Tomcat 6"
cmd /c bin\shutdown.bat
timeout 5
cmd /c bin\startup.bat
```

After building the project, I realized it didn't work, as the Jenkins is in Linux and the remote Tomcat is in Windows. So finally I got to a conclusion that I might have to be able to access the remote Windows command line from the Linux shell.

Any good solutions for this?

The last log of building and deploying the `.war` file ended like the following.

```
Deploying /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/POS/target/posapi.war to container Tomcat 7.x Remote
  Redeploying [/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/POS/target/posapi.war]
  Undeploying [/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/POS/target/posapi.war]
  Deploying [/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/POS/target/posapi.war]
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Does it mean that the reload is also successfully done?

Comment: Are you using any slave concept here?
You need run the command on windows server, how you are trying pointing to that particular machine.

Comment: @ChandraSekhar by running the postbuild batch script. Do you think that'll work?

Comment: As Mentioned above you are deploying the .war to tomcat in windows.How You configure it by Container plugin or script file.

You want to run the batch command on windows so how you try to configure to run that command in windows.